# Order of contacts' email addresses suggestions in Mail.app

Tags: mail.app, contacts.app

When writing an email with Mail.app, I've noticed that Mail suggests the email adresses of a contact in alphabetical order rather than in the order set up in Contacts.app.

For example, if a contact has 3 associated email addresses work@example.com, home@example.com and other@example.com (in this order) like in the example below
[image]

Mail.app would suggest those adresses in the alphabetical order, that is home@example.com, other@example.com, work@example.com
[image]
I'd like to know if it possible to have Mail reorder these emails suggestions so that they follow the order in the Contacts app.

Thanks in advance.

Configuration
Mojave 10.14.6 (18G103)
Mac mini (fin 2012)